# Kubuntu installer does not detect hdd partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, multi-boot, kubuntu

I am trying to install Kubuntu from a bootable USB drive, on a computer with a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. I also have Windows on this computer and want to keep it.

I would like to install my root on the SSD and the rest (`/home`, swap) on the HDD. In Windows, I created 2 partitions on the HDD, one for Windows and one where I would like to mount my Kubuntu folders.

However, the Kubuntu installer only detect my HDD as a big 1ToB disk. If I want to add partitions on it for Kubuntu, I have to format it.

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Please check UEFI settings, SATA mode or similar. You may find something like RAID, Intel RST, etc. and it needs  to be AHCI for Kubuntu to detect the drives correctly. Do not change modes yet, first you need to install AHCI drivers in Windows or it won't boot.

Comment: Ok, so I checked my SATA mode and indeed it is not in AHCI mode. Finding an AHCI driver does not seem that easy. I couldn't find it on the official site of Asus (my PC is an Asus VivoBookPro17). Do you know where I can find it ?

Comment: It can be done this way (instructions for Windows 8 but it's the same for 10): https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/22631-enable-ahci-windows-8-windows-10-after-installation.html